# What are Kelemvor’s divine servants?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Besides his mortal worshippers, the Doomguides, how does Kelemvor enforce his will on the material plane (or anywhere besides the Fugue Plane, really)? Does he have angels in his service? Maybe not since Kelemvor is Neutral and does not reside in the upper planes. I’ve seen it suggested somewhere that he would use Avatars of Death as his servants, but I don’t know if there’s any canon support of this.

**Basically, the question is: some gods have Angels. What equivalent does Kelemvor have?**

Comment: What makes you think not all gods have Angels? My understanding is that they're supposed to be a generic sort of "divine servant'. A category akin to "Elemental" or "Dragon".

Answer (score 3):

The most recent official printed material on the Forgotten Realms, the 5e's *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, does not mention any specific divine servants. In general, angels are servants to all sorts of deities.

If you are interested in past lore, the 2e *Faiths and Avatars* discusses the various manifestations and servants of all the deities as they were in 1370s DR. For Kelemvor, we can read (pg 85) that pers, einheriar and watchghosts could be sent by Kelemvor.

Finally, if you are considering of some sort of reaper, it is worth noting that "the Reaper" of FR is the deity Myrkul (pg 35 of SCAG).